# Count by specific increments. Technical issue on a recursive call?

Tags: java, recursion

Write a method countToBy that accepts integer parameters n and m and that produces an output indicating how to count to n in increments of m separated by commas.

The call countToBy(25,4); prints:   1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25

mine prints: , 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25

I can't just add a System.out.print("1"); because not all the calls should print 1 at the beginning. Other than the first element, the code is working perfectly. I've tried everything to get that first element but either I get "111111" or nothing at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: this is not homework just practicing recursion! :)

```
public static void countToBy(int n, int m) {

  if(n < 1 || m < 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  if(n == 0 || m == 0) {
    System.out.print("");
  }
  else {

    int store = n - m; 

    if(store > 0){
      countToBy(n - m , m );
      System.out.print (", " + n );  // issue is here
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: try after int store = n - m; if (n<1) n=1 :P

Comment: also change this countToBy(n - m , m ); to countToBy(store , m ); rather than calculating it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your condition `if(store > 0)` stops you from printing the current value. What you should do is use the condition to continue recursing but always print the current value of `n` because if it reached that point, it passed all your previous checks so its a valid value.

Change

```
// ... rest of your code
int store = n - m;
if(store > 0){
      countToBy(n - m , m );
      System.out.print(", " + n );
}
// ...
```

To:

```
// ... rest of your code
int store = m - n;
if(store > 0){
    countToBy(store, m );     // use store instead of n-m because you already calculated that
    System.out.print(", ");   // print the comma inside the statement, because (store > 0) means we have more elements to come
} 
System.out.print(n);          // print the current element
// ...
```

Additionally, your second `if` statement doesn't really serve any purpose because if either `n` or `m` is 0, then it will satisfy the first `if` and throw an exception without ever reaching the second `if`. Therefore, you can remove it.

Here's what your code can shorten to (I omitted the `if n < 1, m < 1` check for brevity):

```
public static void countToBy(int n, int m) {
   int store = n - m; 
    if(store > 0) {
        countToBy(store, m );
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.print(n);
}
```

[**Here's a DEMO**](https://ideone.com/oUqcxQ)

Comment: @nem035. It works fine except for this case countToBy(1,0); This will not stop and run forever. I have posted solution below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46974133/1372290

Comment: Hi @i.AsifNoor, thanks for your comment. If you read my answer carefully, I've omitted the checks for `n < 1` or `m < 1` on purpose to demonstrate the general algorithm and I left it to the OP to finish up the base case

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(n == 0 || m == 0) {
    System.out.print("");
}
```

To:

```
if(n == 1 || m == 1){
   System.out.print(n);
}
```

`n` and `m` should never be < 1 since that would cause an error that you already check for, if either is equal to one, simply display the first character.

Comment: I believe the point of checking if `m` and `n` are negative is to protect the **first call** to the method. Same thing goes for zeros.

Comment: Look over the first two `if` statements, the second will never be useful which is why I believe this person mistyped and by checking if they are equal to `1`, will be able to print out that number before the rest are recursively called.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I didn't read that properly. The second statement here is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
void countToBy(int to,int offset) {

        if (to == 0 || offset ==0) {
            System.out.print(0) ; //base caes
            return;
        }
        if ( to<=offset) {
            System.out.print(to) ; //base caes
            return;
        } else  {

            countToBy(to-offset,offset); //recursive step
            System.out.print (", "+to);
        }
    }
```